# Obtaining US sponsor

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration

I have arranged an event in the US in New York for Aug 2021 and two of the speakers are from London (British) and two from India.

I understand that one needs a B1 visa for this charity event on world peace and none of the speakers are paid other than flights and accommodation.
My problem is that I am based in London and arranging the event and yet I need a US sponsor (institution) to act as the body applying for the B1 visa. I have tried to convince US universities to be the sponsor but no success.

Could a US citizen be our sponsor?

Comment: If the event is taking place in the US, is the charity registered there? Who are the officials of the charity and where are they based?

Comment: Something doesn't quite make sense here. US institutions do not apply for B1 visas; the individual traveler does. Further, what does it mean that you have "arranged" an event? Are you the event organizer? In that case you would be the "sponsor" if such a thing was necessary. But it probably isn't.